# Is it possible to "include" another wordpress post/page?

Tags: plugins

I am currently using a custom php file which is residing in the root of my themes folder. I created a Page and set the Template to my custom php file's template name.

#### Is it possible for my php code to `include` another wordpress post/page?

1. I am only interested in rendering and not redirecting.
2. If possible, I want the entire html. This includes the header, footer and everything that should be shown in that page/post.

Comment: Yes - can you explain more about why you need to include the post? Are you trying to create an exact duplicate of an existing post, or are you embedding it somehow within another view? WP may have a built-in way to handle your goal if you can help us understand better what the specific goal is.

Comment: @WebElaine I have a custom template php files which decides if the visitor is fraudulent. If not, render the entire HTML from a post otherwise send to somewhere else.

Comment: It sounds like in your "if fraudulent" statement you could put: if fraudulent redirect; else `template_redirect` to send them on to the right page. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect